# Unable to connect solar wind ARM with Windows Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, arm, windows-server-2019, solarwinds-orion

I installed Active Directory on my Windows 2019 server. And setup local solar wind access resources manager on it but getting below error and unable to connect with arm server

Error while connecting:
[image: Error while connecting]

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check the below ports as shown in the figure below as the error that you have encountered clearly states that firewall is blocking some ports for successful communication.

[image: Solarwind ARM AD connection]

Also, please find the below link for reference to configure Active Directory connection details: -

https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/arm/content/active-directory-scans.htm